# do while loop. C program

Tags: c, if-statement, do-while, logical-operators, logical-or

I dont know what is wrong with my program. Whenever I try the output it only prints the `It is the season of Winter`, I don't know how to fix this.

```c
int main() {
    int answer = 1;
    int mon;

    do {
        printf("Input a month : ");
        scanf("%d", &mon);

        if (mon == 1 || 2 || 12)
            printf("It is the season of winter\n\n\n");
        
        if (mon == 3 || 4 || 5) 
            printf("It is the season of spring\n\n\n");
        
        if (mon == 6 || 7 || 8)
            printf("It is the season of summer\n\n\n");
        
        if (mon == 9 || 10 || 11)
            printf("It is the season of fall\n\n\n");
        
        printf("Would you like to try again? (1= YES / 0= NO) : ");
        scanf("%d", &answer);
    
    } while (answer !=0);
    
    printf("\n\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might want to revisit your learning material about operators. `mon == 1 || 2 || 12` will not do what you expect. You need `(mon==1) || (mon==2) || (mon==12)`

Comment: You should never use `scanf` or other IO functions without checking the return value.

Comment: The extra parentheses here are not required, but not necessarily a bad idea.  Mostly a matter of personal style.

Comment: @paddy The extra parentheses are not required from C standard view but if you ever have to run your code through some MISRA check, your view may change. ;)

Answer (score 4):

The conditions in the if statements are incorrect.

For example let's consider this if statement

```
if (mon == 1 || 2 || 12)
```

It is equivalent to

```
if ( ( mon == 1 ) || ( 2 ) || ( 12 ) )
```

So as the second and the third operands of the logical OR operators are not equal to 0 then the condition always evaluates to logical true.

From the C Standard (6.5.14 Logical OR operator)

> 3 The || operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare
> unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.

You need to write

```
if (mon == 1 || mon == 2 || mon == 12)
```

Also instead of the series of if statements it would be better to write if -else if statements like

```
    if (mon == 1 || mon == 2 || mon == 12)
        printf("It is the season of winter\n\n\n");
    
    else if (mon == 3 || mon == 4 || mon == 5) 
        printf("It is the season of spring\n\n\n");
    
    else if (mon == 6 || mon == 7 || mon == 8)
        printf("It is the season of summer\n\n\n");
    
    else if (mon == 9 || mon == 10 || mon == 11)
        printf("It is the season of fall\n\n\n");
```

In this case for example if the expression of the first if statement evaluates to true all other if statements will be skipped.  That is in this case you can avoid redundant evaluations of expressions of the if statements.

Comment: You're right, i need to re visit some of the fundamentals. I was so frustrated and forgot the right operators to use. Thank you so much! What a life saver

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question should print all four seasons because all tests evaluate to true:

```
if (mon == 1 || 2 || 12)
```

evaluates the first condition `mon == 1` which is only true for January, then for other months it evaluates `2` which is non zero, hence true, so the whole condition is true and `It is the season of winter` is printed. The same happens for all four tests.

You should write this instead:

```
if (mon == 1 || mon == 2 || mon == 12)
```